# Accessing a specific field using Type Embedding?

Tags: rest, go

I was wondering how can I access a single specific field using go's version of inheritance?

Right now I have 3 Structs, the `Trade` struct is the base struct for all other structs but my two other structs only require a few fields from the base struct. Is there anyway to only inherit those structs?

I want the body of the request to be the Trade Struct, then I want to turn it into an `internalTrade` and finally I want to return a `tradesubmmited` response.

```
type Trade struct {
    ClientTradeId string `json:"clientTradeId"`
    Date          int    `json:"date"`
    Quantity      string `json:"quantity"`
    Price         string `json:"price"`
    Ticker        string `json:"ticker"`
}
type InternalTrade struct {
    Id string `json:"Id"`
    Trade *Trade `json:"Trade"`
}

type TradeSubmitted struct {

    TradeId string `json:"TradeId"`
    Trade *Trade `json:"ClientTradeId"`

}

func createTrade(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    var trade Trade
    var internalTrade InternalTrade
    var tradeSubmitted TradeSubmitted

    _ = json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&trade)


    internalTrade.Id = string(rand.Intn(1000000))
    internalTrade.Trade.ClientTradeId = trade.ClientTradeId
    internalTrade.Trade.Date = trade.Date
    internalTrade.Trade.Quantity = trade.Quantity
    internalTrade.Trade.Price = trade.Price
    internalTrade.Trade.Ticker = trade.Ticker

    tradeSubmitted.Trade.ClientTradeId = trade.ClientTradeId
    tradeSubmitted.TradeId = internalTrade.Id

    trades = append(trades, internalTrade)

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&tradeSubmitted)

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: embedding is not inheritance. In your model, `Trade` is simply a field of the struct.

It looks like in your model the `InternalTrade` is simply `Trade` with an id. The way you're initializing `InternalTrade` is wrong, because `internalTrade.Trade` is nil, and you're setting members of a nil-pointer to a struct. Instead:

```
internalTrade.Id = string(rand.Intn(1000000))
internalTrade.Trade=&trade
```

Alternatively:

```
type InternalTrade struct {
    Id string `json:"Id"`
    Trade Trade `json:"Trade"`
}
```

and

```
internalTrade.Id = string(rand.Intn(1000000))
_ = json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&internalTrade.Trade)
```

Finally, `TradeSubmitted` does not really have anything common with `Trade`, and you can do

```
type TradeSubmitted struct {
    TradeId string `json:"TradeId"`
    ClientTradeID string `json:"ClientTradeId"`
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Would something like this work as well?

 internal := InternalTrade{
  Id: strconv.Itoa(rand.Intn(1000000)),
  Trade: &trade,
 }